# Flutter: Drawer ListView Body Overflows

Tags: flutter

[Here is a minimum reproducible example.](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=2e1d903fdd730828736264b28488a5a5)

The drawer in the given example has three parts:

- A header
- A body
- A footer

I'd like header and footer visible at all times and would like body to be scrollable, ListView is viable for this.

However, as the children of the ListView grows, it increases its height as well, causing (i) height overflow and (ii) taking the footer down with itself.

How can I fix the size of the body to be *until footer* at maximum?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Ubuntu 21.04 5.11.0-40-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8) (installed as snap)
- Target environment is web.

Comment: you need only one column: `Column(children: [Header(), Expanded(child: ListView()), Footer()])`

Comment: Solved it. Thanks. Write that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: no problem, your welcome to write a self answer ;-)

Comment: @pskink mostly answers on comment section.(i found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I have thought grouping Header and Body as one was a good idea since they should be separated with `spaceBetween` from footer. However, keeping all of them under one `Column` with the exception that Body is wrapped with `Expanded` solves both issue.

So the final solution is:

```dart
children: const [
  _DrawerHeader(),
  Expanded(child: _DrawerBody()),
  _DrawerFooter(),
],
```

With this method, Body occupies all the area it requires.